# Prevent internal error on false from file_get_contents

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to use the following to detect if a file exists, however there is a warning triggered when when this is the case. It works fine when `file_get_contents` does not return false.

```
$nothing = "http://www.google.com/bababababa.doc";
if (false === file_get_contents($nothing,0,null,0,1)) {
    echo "File Not Found";
} else {
    echo "File Found";
}
```

Comment: `@file_get_contents` perhaps?

Comment: Yes! I imagine so!

Comment: Using the error suppression operator (@) is ***bad practice*** and should be avoided whenever possible. It makes stuff harder to debug because your code starts failing silently. It is much better to handle errors rather than suppress them.

Comment: Agreed @jfadich. My comment was diagnostic, not prophylactic.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll assume that you only want to hide this error from your logs, because of course you have `display_errors` turned off on a production server.

You could just hide your errors away with the [`@` error suppression operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), but that's a bad road to start down. Instead you want to define an error handler:

```
<?php
// define the custom handler that just returns true for everything
$handler = function ($err, $msg, $file, $line, $ctx) {return true;}

$nothing = "http://www.google.com/bababababa.doc";
// update the error handler for warnings, keep the old value for later
$old_handler = set_error_handler($handler, E_WARNING);
// run the code
$result = file_get_contents($nothing);
// go back to normal error handling
set_error_handler($old_handler);

if (false === $result) {
    echo "File Not Found";
} else {
    echo "File Found";
}
```